# Prolog "operator expected error" on predicate commands sequence

Tags: prolog

This very simple Prolog example from my study material is giving me an "Operator Expected" error:

```
greet(alice):- 
        write(‘How are you doin, pal?’).
greet(bob):- 
        write(‘Awfully nice to see you!’).
```

What an I missing ?

Comment: Does your source code actually contain ‘ and ’?

Answer (score 3):

Like @larsman mentioned in comments, substitute `’` and `‘` with `'`:

```
greet(alice):-
        write('How are you doin, pal?').
greet(bob):-
        write('Awfully nice to see you!').
```